# How to filter search using tablesorter

Tags: tablesorter

I'm using the tablesorter search/filter plugin to search names from a list. so when i type in a letter corresponding to the letters in the list will display. I used this: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-external-inputs.html as a reference.
Below is my code:

```
var $table = $('#table').tablesorter({
    sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]],
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
    widgetOptions : {
        filter_columnFilters: false,
        filter_saveFilters : true,
    }
}); 
$.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch( $table, $('.search-subaccounts') );
```

HTML:

```
<input class="search-subaccounts" type="search" data-column="1"/>
```

I'm trying to filter names based on first name.
so when i try to execute it, gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindSearch' of undefined
```

I dont know why it says 'filter' is undefined whereas i tried executing exactly the way its in the demo. What did i do wrong here?
Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the widget file isn't being included since the `bindSearch` function isn't being found - it's included with the filter widget. Make sure you load the following files on your page (theme file name will vary depending on your choice):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.blue.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes, i have all these files loaded except for the theme css file. just that i have all the unminified versions of the files.

Comment: Are you using the most up-to-date files? `bindSearch` wasn't added until v2.13.3.

Comment: yup..i was using an older version. Thanks